# Net monitoring program for Ubuntu that can filter by pid, showing destination IPs with the ability to save logs

Tags: networking, vpn, wireshark, nethogs

Sometimes I use cloud gaming service. The problem, however, is that all my Internet traffic goes through the vpn by default. I want to exclude game traffic from vpn and I know how to do it, but what i don't know is how to make a list of the ip ranges accessed by the application (more precisely, a separate browser with a web application). I've tried nethogs - it doesn't show ip, only pid and is not good for saving logs somewhere. Tried wireshark - great for filtering ip but it's completely unclear what process was accessing them.

**Is there a network traffic monitoring program for Ubuntu that can filter by pid, showing destination IPs with the ability to save logs in a readable form?**

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -pWnct | grep <app name>
```

- p - for PIDs
- W - for IPs
- n - for numeric ports and hosts
- c - for continous listen
- t - for only TCP packets (optional)